# How to properly MVC this task?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, validation, service

My task is to upload file.

```
class FileUploadController : Controller {
     public ActionResult Index(HttpPostedFileBase postedFile) {
          // When and how to validate it and return appropriate view and model data

          // How to store the file in database and appropriately return view and model data
     }
}
```

Validation requires to check if `filename` already exists(database access) and if `file extension`(database access) is supported.

So far I architected it like this:

```
   class FileUploadController : Controller {
         public ActionResult Index(HttpPostedFileBase postedFile) {
              FileUploadModel model=new FileUploadModel();
              model.UploadedFile = postedFile;
              FileUploadService service = new FileUploadService();
              bool valid = service.Validate(postedFile);
              if (valid) {
                   FileUploadViewModel viewModel = service.Save(postedFile); 
                   return View("some_view", viewModel);
              }
              else {
                   return View("some_view", service.ViewModel);
              }
         }
    }

    public class FileUploadModel
    {
         public HttpPostedFileBase UploadedFile { get; set; }
    }

    class FileUploadViewModel {
         public ModelState ModelState;
         public String Filename;
    }

    public class FileUploadService
    {
        private FileUploadViewModel viewModel = new FileUploadViewModel();


        public FileUploadViewModel Save(FileUploadModel fileUploadModel)
        {
             // here i will just save it to the database
             // and return viewModel with valid state
        }

        public bool Validate(FileUploadModel fileUploadModel)
        {
             // I do the filename, size, etc validation here together with database validation if the file exists and appropriately attach errors to viewModel.ModelState so views can render the error
        }
    }
```

As you can see my validate method populates `viewModel.ModelState` and my Save method returns new `FileUploadViewModel`. I really can't make up my mind how to design this so it can grow.

My questions are: 
 - If suddenly update action is added and my service serve update method, I will need to return different data as ViewModel and the validation would be different, should I create new ViewModel class and new Validation..?
 - Does my validation occur at valid place?

Comment: Hard to understand what your trying to achieve. Your `FileUploadViewModel` class should not contain a property `ModelState` (you add model state errors to the `Controller.ModelState` property in the POST method if there are validation errors). And how will your validation of the file name work? - what if a user uploads 2 different files with the same name but from different directories (the files path is never posted back)? And you should not be storing files in a database anyway - use a file server

Comment: My goal is to organize things, about how the actual validation will occur is not what i am asking for. I am asking where the actual validation should occur and what happens when there is needed different validators. Also how would ViewModel data should be managed for different occasions, depending on if there was Add action or Update action executed

Comment: The validation should occur in the controller. If the `fileUploadModel` contains an invalid property then you add a model state error using `ModelState.AddModelError()`. But a more robust approach is be to create a custom validation attribute and apply it to your `UploadedFile` property so that its all done for you. For example, [This article](http://blog.tomasjansson.com/creating-custom-unobtrusive-file-extension-validation-in-asp-net-mvc-3-and-jquery/) shows a `ValidationAttribute` that validates the file extension

Comment: If i add validation in the controller isn't it kinda becoming messy when i will need to open database connection, and than afterwards if its valid i will call the service method Save, which will again open connection, i want to centralize it into a service, but because the ModelState is attached to the controller it messes everything

Comment: You can still call a service (and that's what you should be doing anyway), but your `SaveFile()` method might for example return a `List<string>` containing a list of errors which you can then add to `ModelState` (or if there were no errors, then it actually does the save). Not sure you need a separate `ValidateFile()` method which actually means you are opening the connection twice. But most validation such as file size or file type if appropriate can be done without a database connection and as I noted before, I can't see any point in validating a file name.

Comment: Well.. alright, thanks for the opinions!